# Volume of a solid using disk method

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I have the following homework problem which I can't seem to get right. The question stated is:

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded
>   by the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{25}$ and the line y=1  about the line
>   y=1.

So I came up with the following integral and solved to get $\frac{8}{3}\pi$ but the correct answer according to my homework is $\frac{16}{3}\pi$.
$$\pi\int_0^5\left(1-\frac{2x^2}{25}+\frac{x^4}{625}\right)dx$$

So is my integral correct and I'm simply not doing the math right when solving it? Or am I just missing something in the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to integrate from -5 to 5 or multiply your integral by two. That does the trick

Comment: But in all the other similar problems, I integrate similarly starting from zero and I still get the correct answer. And all the other similar problems also involve a revolution around both the x- and y- axes, and my answers there were all correct.

Comment: What other similar problems do you have in mind? No two problems are identical. In this case, the curve crosses y=1 at points (-5,1) and (5,1). Therefore you have to integrate from -5 to 5. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: I understand...I only drew half the graph (only the first quadrant)! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Exactly! You got it

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to multiple it by $2$, because you set the lower bound $0$ instead of $-5$.